# System.InvalidOperationException when creating new instance of window in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this code stolen from somewhere else on this website:

```cs
public static class WindowManager
    {
        public static T GetWindow<T>()
        {
            var t = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<T>().FirstOrDefault();
            if (t == null)
            {
                t = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
            }
            return t;
        }

        public static T CreateOrFocusWindow<T>()
        {
            var t = GetWindow<T>();
            if (t is Window)
            {
                var window = t as Window;
                if (window.Visibility != Visibility.Visible)
                    window.Show();
                if (window.WindowState == WindowState.Minimized)
                    window.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
                window.Focus();
            }
            return t;
        }
    }
```

Its simple implementation of one instance of any window. But it creates certain issue.

```cs
private async void Button_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            await Task.Run(WindowManager.CreateOrFocusWindow<Window1>);
        }
```

But it returns exception in line `var t = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<T>().FirstOrDefault();` - `System.InvalidOperationException - The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.`

I don't have any idea how to solve it without removing `WindowManager`, but it simplifies code so much I really want to keep it.

Edit

This fixes exception, but UI is locked despite using async/await.

```cs
private async void Button_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            LoadingOn();
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Dispatcher.Invoke(() => //InvokeAsync changes nothing
                {
                    WindowManager.CreateOrFocusWindow<FitnessWindow>();
                });
            });
            LoadingOff();
        }
```

Comment: Why are you using Task.Run?

Comment: @Clemens long operation inside constructor. I don't want to lock UI.

Comment: CreateOrFocusWindow won't lock anything.

Comment: I have used dispatcher to bypass exception but this is exactly what happens, UI is locked for a few seconds. Not the behavior I want.

Comment: See the answers to the question marked as duplicate, or the dozens of similar questions and answers. You can't access `Application.Current.Windows` from a thread other than the UI thread.

Comment: @Clemens so, its not possible to run task asynchronously in WPF? Thats very bad news.

Comment: That is well possible. You must however use the Dispatcher to access UI elements from non-UI threads.

Comment: @Clemens I have used dispatcher and UI still gets locked for a few seconds when creating new window.

Comment: How are we supposed to help you with this when you aren't showing us your actual code?

Comment: @Clemens its not like there is any point, since someone already marked it as duplicate. But if you are actually eager to help (very rare thing on stackoverflow), I will post the code.

Comment: Anyway, a new Window has to be created on the UI thread. If its creation takes time, try to move all unnecessary code out of its constructor.

Comment: @Clemens this sounds like a plan but my `MainWindow` will become huge mess, because I will have to gather a lot of data for each window before its created. Now its clean and tidy (each window gets own data in own code behind).

Comment: Move that code into an async Loaded event handler where you may run a Task.

Comment: Task.Run with only Dispatcher.Invoke is totally pointless.

Comment: @Clemens never heard about `async loaded event`, checking google.

Comment: A handler of the Window's Loaded event, declared as `async void`, with an `await Task.Run(...)` call, just like your Click handler.

Comment: @Clemens ok this is brilliant and elegant. But I do not want to open the window until data is ready. Otherwise I would have to move loading spinner to each new window, and I'm pretty lazy.

Comment: Well, then you have to prepare the Window state before creating the Window. It should be clear now that the constructor is the wrong place, as it must be called in the UI thread and will inevitably block it.